# Serverless Toolkit for Private Lambda Functions

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-code-deploy, aws-serverless

Using the *serverless toolkit (serverless.com)*, I'd like to deploy some *AWS Lambda* functions that are used for internal purposes only (private).

*API Gateway* events can be set to private requiring a key; however, the endpoint would still be exposed to the public and add overhead of gateway to invocations.

I was hoping to find some invocation event such as RPC.

**What event type can I use with serverless to invoke a non-publicly exposed Lambda function during deploys in CodePipeline or manual invocation?**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for a private endpoint in API Gateway? 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/

Comment: That's a solution, but really I didn't want to use API Gateway to execute the function at all. Instead I found I can just ship the function without any event bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the serverless event bindings/configuration for the Lambda function.

The function will deploy without setting up a dependency on another AWS service.